# Сброс стилей для FireFox

Tags: css

Господа. У меня есть стиль "overflow: auto;" и все бы хорошо, но firefox встраивает горизонтальную полосу прокрутки в сам блок, от этого одна левая недвижимая часть получается ниже других блоков.

Пробовала вновь сбрасывать стили, прописав их в главном css файле, но проблема не устраняется и, сдается мне, не устранится, раз чертов skroll встает в блок. Никто не сталкивался? А то обидно, когда все это косячно лишь для одного браузера.

Итак,
а вдруг

html код

```
<div class="wpb_wrapper">
        <div class="outlaymine">
<div class="deeperoutlay">

    <table style="width: 90%" border="0">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <th class="staytit">Категория</th>
    <th>кол-во</th>
    <th>Основная цена(1 сутки)</th>
    <th>Будни(более 2-х суток)</th>
    <th>Week-end (пятница-воскресенье)</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="stay" style="text-align: left;">Стандарт</td>
    <td style="text-align: center;">11</td>
    <td style="text-align: center;">3 600</td>
    <td style="text-align: center;">1 800</td>
    <td style="text-align: center;">6 700</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="stay" style="text-align: left;">Комфорт</td>
    <td style="text-align: center;">11</td>
    <td style="text-align: center;">4 200</td>
    <td style="text-align: center;">2 100</td>
    <td style="text-align: center;">7 800</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="stay" style="text-align: left;">Комфорт+</td>
    <td style="text-align: center;">6</td>
    <td style="text-align: center;">4 600</td>
    <td style="text-align: center;">2 300</td>
    <td style="text-align: center;">8 600</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="stay" style="text-align: left;">Люкс</td>
    <td style="text-align: center;">4</td>
    <td style="text-align: center;">7 200</td>
    <td style="text-align: center;">3 600</td>
    <td style="text-align: center;">13 400</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="stay" style="text-align: left;">Доп.место</td>
    <td style="text-align: center;"></td>
    <td style="text-align: center;">1 000</td>
    <td style="text-align: center;">800</td>
    <td style="text-align: center;">2 000</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</div>
        </div>
```

CSS стили

```
.outlaymine {position:relative;}
.deeperoutlay {overflow-x: auto;overflow-y: visible;width: 80%;margin-left: 100px;}
.stay {background-color: #0074d9;color: #fff;position: absolute;left: 12px;width: 70px;background-color: rgb(87, 169, 211) !important;}
.staytit {background-color: #0074d9;color: #fff;position: absolute;left: 12px;width: 70px;background-color: rgb(87, 169, 211) !important;height: 20%;}
```

Comment: overflow-y: auto; а так?

Comment: overflow-x: auto;
overflow-y: visible;

но это не решает проблемы. собственно, я вообще не понимаю, каким образом scroll внедряется в блок и только в firefox.

Comment: покажите тогда код этого блока?

Comment: Показала. Весь код. Все стили.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может, reset.css решит проблему. Скачайте любой и подключите его первым в html файле.